# Runnable Jar executes fine on Windows but not on Debian

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, jar, executable-jar

I have no issue executing my runnable jar file exported from eclipse when the file is double clicked or run from the command line.  I have also tested this on my other PC running Windows and everything works fine.  If, however, I try to execute the runnable jar on Debian (Kali specifically) with the command:
`java -jar ChromeGrabber2.jar` I get `Error: Could not find or load main class chromegrabber.ApplicationUI`.

My 'MANIFEST.MF' looks like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: .
Main-Class: chromegrabber.ApplicationUI
```

I'm just tearing my hair out at the moment as to why it won't work.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Check if jar indeed contains required class

Comment: It does contain the required class.